# How to use Java synchronized keyword correctly?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am testing the synchronized functionality in java but it seems that i am not using it correctly.  I want two thread to increment an integer and with using synchronized keyword in the signature of the method the result of the increments should be 200000 but what i am getting is less than 200000 that means that the threads are not synchronized correctly.

My code :

```
public class Threadproblem extends Thread {
    static long counter;
    synchronized public void run() {
        for (int i=0; i<100000;i++) {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Threadproblem thr=new Threadproblem();
        Threadproblem thr2=new Threadproblem();
        thr.start();
        thr2.start();
        try {
            thr.join();
            thr2.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Counts:"+counter);
    }
}
```

Execution:

```
Counts:137978
```

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but FYI, `synchronized void run()...` is _always_ a bad idea. Synchronizing the entire body of the `run()` method says that you only want one thread at a time to execute that `for` loop. But if that's the case, then there would be no point in using threads. The whole point of threads is to let them run _concurrently_ with each other.

Comment: Vague title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Correct synchronization requires that all accesses to the protected variable(s) be performed while holding *the same* monitor.  For an instance method, the `synchronized` keyword causes the method automatically to acquire the monitor of the instance on which it is invoked.  You have two separate instances of `Threadproblem`, so each is using its own monitor.  That provides no synchronization at all.

One way to fix this while using `synchronized` would be to give your class a synchronized, *static* method for incrementing the counter.  Synchronized static methods use a monitor associated with the class on which they are defined, so your two instances of `ThreadProblem` would then use the same monitor:

```
public class Threadproblem extends Thread {
    static long counter;

    synchronized static void incrementCounter() {
        counter++;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000;i++) {
            Threadproblem.incrementCounter();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Threadproblem thr = new Threadproblem();
        Threadproblem thr2 = new Threadproblem();

        thr.start();
        thr2.start();
        try {
            thr.join();
            thr2.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Counts:" + counter);
    }       
}
```

Or as @HiranChaudhuri suggested in comments, you could achieve the same by making the two threads use the same `Runnable` object, with the synchronized method belonging to that object.  Example:

```
public class Threadproblem implements Runnable {
    static long counter;

    synchronized public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000;i++) {
            counter++;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Threadproblem problem = new Threadproblem();

        // Note: instances of plain Thread:
        Thread thr = new Thread(problem);
        Thread thr2 = new Thread(problem);

        thr.start();
        thr2.start();
        try {
            thr.join();
            thr2.join();
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        System.out.println("Counts:" + counter);
    }       
}
```

This is better anyway, regardless of the synchronization issue, because extending `Thread` is almost always the wrong thing to do.  You should define a thread's work by giving it an appropriate `Runnable`, not by overriding the `run()` method of `Thread` itself.

Note that there is also a potential for data races between the main thread and the two additional ones, but these are already avoided because starting a thread and joining one provide appropriate ordering semantics between the two threads involved.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,but if i have invoked 2 times the start method for the same instance it will throw an IllegalThreadStateException so what should i do?

Comment: Do not run the start() method on the same instance of Thread twice. Create two Thread instances using the same Runnable.

Comment: In the original question (as intended, not as erroneously implemented), and in the second part of this answer, there's no real thread overlap - because the sync is held across the entire counting loop.  The first part achieves finer-grained overlap, at the 'increment' level.  In general, both are useful, though the OP may care to consider the difference between the two.

Comment: Might be good to mention the AtomicInteger class at least for others trying to do integer++.

Answer (score 2):

Each execution of 'run' synchronized on its own object, which means you have no synchronization at all.

You need to synchronize on the same object.  In your case, the class might be suitable. Express this as a 'synchronized' statement naming the object - in this case the class literal - to be synchronized on.

```
public void run() {
   synchronized (Threadproblem.class) { 
      ... 
   }
}
```

Comment: Since the counter is static, synchonizing on the class should be best.

Answer (score 0):

Each Object in Java has an implicit lock, which is the element that allows synchronization and mutual exclusion. Each time you call a non-static function on a specific object, its lock gets acquired and no other thread can call the dynamic function on that object until it gets released by the first thread.

So what you should actually be doing is this:

- You create a new class with the method you want to be executed un mutual exclusion
- You create **one single** object of that class in your main method
- Each thread calls the synchronized function trough **that object**.
  It this way, only one thread at the time can acquire the lock and increment the counter in mutual exclusion.

Here's a good example: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-level-lock-in-java/

```
// Java program to illustrate
// Object lock concept

// Class
// Extending Runnable interface
class Geek implements Runnable {

    // Method of this class
    public void run() { Lock(); }

    // Synchronization of non-static methods
    // (object lock) as different synchronized
    // non-static methods are called in both threads

    // Then both threads need to acquire the object lock
    // After one is acquired, the other thread must wait
    // for one thread to finish the executing
    // before the other thread starts to execute.
    public void Lock()
    {
        System.out.println(
            Thread.currentThread().getName());
        synchronized (this)
        {
            System.out.println(
                "in block "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            System.out.println(
                "in block "
                + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " end");
        }
    }

    // Main driver method
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creating an object of above class
        // in the main() method
        Geek g = new Geek();

        // Sharing the same object across two Threads

        // Here, t1 takes g
        Thread t1 = new Thread(g);
    
        // Here, t2 takes g
        Thread t2 = new Thread(g);

        // Creating another object of above class
        Geek g1 = new Geek();

        // Here, t3 takes g1
        Thread t3 = new Thread(g1);

        // setname() method is used to change
        // name of the thread
        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
        t3.setName("t3");

        // start() method beginning the execution of threads
        // as JVM calls the run() method of thread
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Having one single object is a bad showcase, unless it is ensured by using a singleton pattern. Be aware the counter is static, so there is only one for all instances. Synchronization should happen on this static object, or the class.

Comment: Usually, that does not show anything, because each thread t1, t2, t3 has already terminated before the next one is even started.

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri, Singleton is a useful pattern sometimes, but what value would it add in this case? How is creating a singleton class any better than simply creating one instance of the class in `main()` and passing it to both threads?

Comment: @HiranChaudhuri, Re, "synchronization should happen on this static object..." Yes. The underlying priciple there is that the scope and extent of a lock object should be the same as the scope and extent of the data that it protects. If the data (as in this case) are `static` members of the class, then the lock should be a `static` member of the same class. If the data are instance variables, then the lock should be an instance variable, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this task without need of synchronization.
Just be sure that increment operation is atomic.
Use `AtomicLong` and its methods instead of `counter++`.

`static AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong(0);`

`counter.addAndGet(1);`

Comment: This is a question about 'synchronized'.  If synchronization is done correctly, there is no need to use Atomic variables (that is a valid alternative to using synchronization, just not one relevant to this question).  The volatile suggestion is just wrong.

Comment: @accessviolation you're right, I'd edited an answer. But I believe we should avoid using locks whenever it's possible, that's why I posted another approach for solving that kind of problem.

Comment: Re, "I believe we should avoid using locks whenever it's possible." OP is trying to learn about threads. We don't need synchronized _or_ atomics—we don't even need threads—if all we want is a program that prints out "200000". Telling OP to use atomics does not explain what went wrong with their experiment. It does not answer the question.